# Multiple PayPal Transactions at once

Tags: php, html, paypal

Are there any PayPal APIs to process multiple transactions at once?  I'm creating a website where a customer may want to purchase multiple items from different vendors.  Currently I have it set up where my website cart redirects the customer to PayPal for each vendor, but I can see this potentially driving customers away.  I've looked around but haven't quite found anything information on this.

Any information on tutorials or the APIs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe PayPal supports something like this. For this to work you would have to pay yourself, and pay each vendor out of your own account, using seperate transactions. This how say Amazon does it.

Comment: @Ramhound good call. add as an answer so I can +1 it!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! I'll look in to doing that.

Comment: To reiterate; this is *not* true. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PayPal definitely supports this. In fact, it offers multiple products to do so.
These are the products you can look at:

1. PayPal Adaptive Parallel Payments
2. PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments
3. PayPal Express Checkout Parallel Payments

All of these support a single checkout flow with multiple receivers.
The basic difference between Adaptive and Express Checkout is that if you choose the Adaptive API's, you can easily change to Chained Payments later.

On the other hand, if you integrate Express Checkout with Parallel Payments, you can make use of the built-in Mobile Express Checkout, which automatically offers a mobile-sized checkout page to mobile devices, and Express Checkout supports 'line items' (item details shown on the checkout page), which Adaptive Payments doesn't at the moment.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/express-checkout
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPParallelPaymens

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look in to this!

Comment: Great; let me know if you run into any issues!

Comment: Worked great! No problems at all.  Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2):

PayPal doesn't support this to my knowledge.  If you want the transaction to be pseudo simultaneous, you can use cURL-Multi: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php and process the transactions asynchronously.  It will still be separate transactions, but it will go more quickly.